# Why undefined behavoir is true in if statement?

Tags: c, undefined-behavior

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int y = 1;
    if (y & (y = 2))
        printf("true \n");

    else
        printf("false \n");
        return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
true
```

In this program there is an undefined behaviour. The output is always `true`. I've tried few compilers. Can anyone explain me why it is `true` all the time?

Comment: you are using bitwise and &, use && for normal "AND operator', also y ==2 if you want to check if its 2.

Comment: Also that code won't work since you are not passing printf anything.

Comment: Pretty sure the point is (0x01 & 0x02) is *false*, yet all compilers he tries *seem* to eval the parenthetical assignment  *first*, resulting in (0x02 & 0x02), which is *true*. I'm quite certain that assignment is no accident, as answers below seems to conclude. (and before anyone asks, I didn't down vote *anyone*).

Comment: well no down votes should be applied to answers on that "assumption".  Pankaj, explain it????

Comment: When you tried this (and you may do well to cite the "lots of compiler" you used and their modes-of-compilation), did you use any optimization, or was it strictly debug builds?

Comment: @TMcKeown I did not down vote anything.

Comment: I want to perform & operation not && operation

Comment: Sorry, I meant explain your code.

Comment: if it were the brackets. why is it undefined? brackets have the highest precedence so i would expect the y =2 assignment to take place before the bitwise and. I will go with @WhozCraig answer, am i missing something?

Comment: @PankajMahato compiling this on clang 3.5 @ -O3 I receive false, so perhaps vary your test beds a bit. Also, she's smart enough to give me this as well, which I'm guessing you already knew: `warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'y' [-Wunsequenced]`

Comment: @WhozCraig I didn't use any optimizations

Comment: There really isn't a "why" here.  Undefined behavior is undefined.

Comment: @DCoder: that's an excellent dupe.  Thanks for digging it up.

Comment: @tesseract  `(y = 2)` evaluation needs to be precede `left_arg & right_arg`,  That does not prevent `left_arg` evaluation from occurring first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because **observed** behavior is not **defined** behavior. The compilers you're using *seem* (by observation solely) to be performing the following:

1. Assign `y = 2`
2. Eval result of step (1)
3. Eval `y`
4. Bitwise-AND the results of steps (2) and (3) above.
5. Eval result from step (4)

The result would be `(2 & 2)`, which is **true**. The problem is, the order of 1-2, then 3 is not standard-defined. It could just as easily be this:

1. Eval `y`
2. Assign `y = 2`
3. Eval result of step (2)
4. Bitwise-AND the results of steps (1) and (3) above.
5. Eval result from step (4)

The result would be `(1 & 2)`, which is **false**

Or it could be something else entirely. Not *all* compilers will do the first, and you cannot assume because the compilers *you* used do, they *all* will. Nor can you assume that *because* they do and you observed that behavior, it is therefore defined; it isn't. **Compilers don't define behavior; the standard does, and compilers are obliged to comply.**

Note: there is a loophole in this era of definition, but it is *not* the norm, and even it is loosely defined by the standard. You will find areas within the standard the say something is "implementation-defined." In such cases the standard points out these areas of divergence with reasonably clarity. In such cases you should consult your implementation for definitive conclusion as to what behavior to expect, and in so doing be prepared to accept the simple a fact that such behavior can only be relied on within the confines of the implementation. This (your sample) is *not* such loophole exception.

My clang 3.5 rig *seems* (by my observation) to run the second sequence, not the first, and I could take your road and assume that "all" the compilers I tried (one of them) behave like that, therefore it is defined to be so. I would be mistaken to do so, as are you in your assumption.

Undefined behavior is just that; *undefined*.

Comment: I hesitate to drag this out any longer, but it is perhaps worth noting that a compiler may detect that the expression `(y & (y = 2))` is undefined (hence neither true nor false), and optimize the whole thing away.  The program may print *nothing at all*.

Comment: @StephenCanon A totally fair point and worthy of the comment-upvote. Or it may decide all UB evals to *false* in my little I-get-to-define-what-UB-is universe. Excellent point. UB, ye art a cruel and heartless wench.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to modify the value of y more than once between sequence points. There is not a standard way on how to handle that behavior. So:

```
i = i++; // gives undefined behavior also
```

valter

Answer (score -2):

Yes, the code will always return `True` Because any non-zero value in any conditional statement is `True`(C-99 above) or `1`(C-99) in C

```
if (y & (y = 2))
    printf("true %d\n");
```

In the if condition 2 is assigned to y first and then 2 is bitwise &'ed with 2.
i.e. 0010 & 0010 it'll return 0010 as a result.

So now you have:

```
if(2)  //Any non-zero value is true
    printf("true %d\n");
```

Comment: -1; There is no guarantee that it will return true.  As the questioner states, the behavior is undefined.  There is no ordering on the evaluation of the two operands to `&`.

Comment: @StephenCanon Dude, I wish u read the whole question! "The output is always true. I've tried lots of compiler. Can anyone explain me why it is true all the time?"

Comment: If you will take the time to read the comments, you will find that it *isn't* true all the time.  Even if it were, that would have absolutely no bearing on whether or not the behavior is undefined.

Comment: got false on  LLVM version 5 compiler with a warning.   warning: unsequenced modification and access to 'y'

Comment: @SaurabhSharma: It is not valid reasoning to deduce from “This has behaved as true in each specific instance I have tested with multiple compilers” that “This is true all the time”. The only way to conclude that “This is true all the time” (where “all the time” is “every standard C implementation” is to deduce it from the rules specified for C in the C standard. The rules of standard C are clear: If you both use an object (`y`) and separately modify it (`y = 2`) in an expression that does not impose an ordering on their evaluation, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: Your second paragraph *briefly* touches on the undefined behavior in question. You assume that sequence, and it appears the compilers he's trying perform just that. However, there is no defined sequence point in the position you noted, and as such it is UB. Everything else in this answer explains why it results in true, to be sure. This is easily the best answer so far, and if this answer simply said "because the compilers you're using *seem* to do this: blah but they're not *required* to, and some don't" I would up-vote this quickly.